# Flutter: How to place the mylocation button on Google Maps at different positions?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm using Google Maps and by default the myLocation button shows up on the topRight corner. I want it at the bottom right corner.
I can't seem to have any property inside GoogleMap widget

```
GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,

          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _currentLocation,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        ),
```

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using** `FloationgButton`

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _currentLocation,
        label: Text('My Location'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
      ),
    );
  }
```

also set with the current location

```
void _currentLocation() async {
   final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
   LocationData currentLocation;
   var location = new Location();
   try {
     currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
     } on Exception {
       currentLocation = null;
       }

    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
        zoom: 17.0,
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: I used the controller.animateCamera from your code to fit into my code and it worked perfectly well. Cheers! It gives much more control. But at the same time, it's strange that we don't have such control out of the box using the GoogleMap widget itself.